# In C++, what is the difference between namespaces and libraries?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am extremely new to C++, what is the difference between the C++ Standard Library and the std namespace. I get them confused and don't know when to use which. Also how does the header files correlate with all this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a class library and a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427223/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-library-and-a-namespace)

Comment: Names defined by the standard library are generally placed into `std` namespace. I'm not sure what you mean by "when to use which" - whenever you wish to use a facility of the C++ standard library, that facility is generally found in `std` namespace.

Comment: @Clu3l3ss Start from reading a book on C++ for beginners. It will be useful.

Comment: By "when to use which," I meant that I don't know how each one works and what the purpose of the std namespace and the C++ standard library is.

Comment: The purpose of the standard library is to give the programmer useful facilities to build upon. The purpose of `std` namespace is to hold the names defined by the standard library, so they don't conflict with the names defined by the program.

Comment: Possibly related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard [template] library is a collection of tools - specifically containers and algorithms - that are useful in a general sense.  It is particularly powerful when the algorithms are applied to the containers - when sorting a vector, for example.

Namespaces serve to decorate the symbols defined within them and thus avoid collisions between symbols defined (usually) by different libraries.  All standard library code is in namespace `std`.  Thus we have, for example, `std::vector`, `std::sort` and a whole lot more.

To pick another library at random, the popular Nlohmann JSON library defines all its symbols in namespace `nlohmann`, and in the unlikely event that this defined a `vector` class, it would not clash with the standard library.

You will often see people on SO (and elsewhere) coding `using namespace std;`, sometimes in a header file, and perhaps you now understand why this practise is not wise.

Does any of that help at all?

Comment: Oh I see now, so the namespace std only contains C++ standard library? Also how do we check which namespace is the library we use contained in?

Comment: Yes, namespace `std` should contain the standard library and nothing else (i.e. don't put your own stuff in it), and to determine what namespace(s) is / are used by any particular library, consult the documentation or the source code.